# Using Java/Selenium to create a String Array of tweets

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to create a string array of tweets made up of all the tweets on a particular page. I have loaded to the page I want and can add the first tweet on that page into the string array and print it. But for some reason, the first tweet gets added over and over rather than getting the first tweet, moving to the second, then the third, etc. Here is my code:

```
String[] tweets = new String[50];
int count=0;

List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='TweetTextSize  js-tweet-text tweet-text']"));
for (WebElement element : elements) {
    if (element.isDisplayed()) {
        tweets[count] = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='TweetTextSize  js-tweet-text tweet-text']")).getText();
        count++;
    }
}

for(int count2=0; count2<tweets.length; count2++)
    System.out.println(tweets[count2]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you doing `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='TweetTextSize  js-tweet-text tweet-text']")).getText();` for a second time? Please use the `element.getText()` instead!

Answer (score 0):

This line does not change depending on your loop variable, so you get the same thing back every time:

```
        tweets[count] = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='TweetTextSize  js-tweet-text tweet-text']")).getText();
```

You probably want:

```
        tweets[count] = element.getText();
```